# Option for nmcli command to get only the name of the NetworkManager connection profiles

Tags: nmcli

I know that by the execution of the command:

```
nmcli con show
```

I get the list of all connection profiles present in the Linux system. For example if I execute the previous command in my Linux Mint system I obtain:

```
$ nmcli con show
NAME             UUID                                  TYPE      DEVICE   
lan0             b89ebc2f-8702-32d1-8dbf-e8d4cf226ce1  ethernet  enp0s25  
lan1             bd0a02cf-65e9-3cf5-8b51-ef05aa204e7c  ethernet  enp5s0f0 
lan2             4b5d75d9-cab9-3ac5-95e5-cbeddf257cc5  ethernet  enp5s0f1 
lan1 with space  63b628f9-7671-41a4-8d2a-be5cfa34c454  ethernet  --       
lan2 with space  1cd1fb7d-0c5d-4105-ba27-c7e6ce7b6ecb  ethernet  --
```

In the example the NAME of the connection profiles contain spaces (see `lan1 with space` and `lan2 with space`).

My need is to execute the previous command and get only the list of the `NAME` of the connection without the column `UUID`, `TYPE`, `DEVICE`.

In the previous example my wished output would be:

```
lan0
lan1
lan2
lan1 with space
lan2 with space
```

Is there an option for the command `nmcli` which gives exactly the previous output?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use it with `-g` (or `--get-values`) to print only the values for the `NAME` field:

```
nmcli -g NAME con
```